# Algorithm which finds biggest n nodes in a tree

Tags: algorithm, search, tree

Lets assume that we have a tree which nodes hold some numbers.
I need to find n biggest numbers in this tree.
I have two algorithms on my mind:
1. Using BFS or DFS iterate over tree and put it's nodes in an array and then sort it using quick sort as example and return n first elements.
Time complexity of this method is O(|V| + |E| + |V|log|V|) spatial is O(|V|)
2. Second is to iterate over tree finding maximum element and marking it n times. So time complexity is O(N*(|V| + |E|)) spatial is O(|V|) too.

Which solution is better and maybe im on the wrong way and there is a much better solution?

Comment: Does the tree provide any guarantees on the relative order of its nodes?  E.g. is it a binary search tree, where the left child is always smaller than its parent and the right child greater than or equal to it?

Comment: No, it's just a generic tree representing e.g. some network.

Comment: OK, in that case it gives you nothing to work with, so (asymptotically speaking) you might as well copy it into an array with a DFS/BDS as the first step.

Comment: Regarding what to do next: Sorting and grabbing the top n items isn't too bad, but you can shave a log factor off (the average time, using an easy pivot selection rule, or the worst-case time, using a complex and slow median-of-medians pivot selection rule) by using quickselect to directly find the nth-largest element, and then simply looping through the array, keeping all the elements >= the one you found.  (Duplicate elements can be handled too, with a little thought.)

Comment: thank you for your advice i did't know about quickselect

Comment: You can maintain the 'biggest N so far' in a sorted list. That should reduce the O(|V|Log|V|) component.

In worst case (but maybe not average) I think that is O(N*|V| + |E|) - requiring O(|V|) inserts into a sorted list. 
If you have a doubly linked list you can keep track of Nth place and only need to insert when you get a node > Nth place.
Other sorted structures would be even faster.
If you have some way of being likely to hit the high value nodes first you can cut down that insert cost significantly.

Comment: PS: In a tree O(|V|)=O(|E|). You can simplify some of your expressions a bit.

Comment: @DanAllen: This is also a good way, provided that instead of adding elements to a sorted list (which is expensive to maintain), you insert them into a *min-heap*.  Whenever the heap reaches size n+1, you delete its minimum element, which can be done in O(log n) time.  This keeps the heap size <= n+1, so each insertion is also O(log n).  At the end, the heap contains the n largest items (in some order), with O(|V|log n) total time used.

Comment: @j_random_hacker. Agreed. There are various sorted and pseudo sorted structures that might help further. But if it turns out N is small it might not be a significant gain once you've ducked sorting the whole list of |V| nodes.

Answer (score 1):

And a standard [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) selection algorithm won't work?

The basic algorithm is (assuming that `k` is the number of items you want to select)

```
create an empty min-heap
for each node (depth-first search)
    if heap.count < k
        heap.Add(node)
    else if node.Value < heap.Peek.Value()
        heap.RemoveSmallest()
        heap.Add(node)
```

When the `for` loop is done, your heap contains the `k` largest values. You can obtain them in ascending order with:

```
while heap.count > 0
    output (heap.RemoveSmallest().Value)
```

If you want them in ascending order, remove them from the heap as above into an array, and then reverse the array.

This algorithm is O(n log k), where `n` is the number of nodes in the tree, and `k` is the number of items you want.

Comment: How can it be O(n log k) if DFS itself is O(|V| + |E|)?

Comment: @s0nicYouth: If the tree has `n` nodes, then depth first search is O(n). However you describe it, it's linear in the number of nodes. The selection algorithm has `n log k`, because insertion into the heap is `log k`, removal is `log k`, and in the worst case, every item is added to and removed from the heap. So `2n log k`, and since we ignore constant factors in asymptotic analysis, it's O(n log k).

Comment: Maybe I'm asking a stupid question but I thought DFS time complexity for V vertexes and E edges is O(V + E) which is essential for me. Why are you saying its O(n)(or O(V) which is the same)?

Comment: @s0nicYouth: It depends on how the tree is defined. My assumption is that you have a tree in which there is only one path to any node. The simplest case would be a binary tree, but you can extend that to a ternary tree, etc., or trees that have varying numbers of nodes. If there can be multiple paths to any given node, then it is indeed O(V + E). In that case, the search algorithm I describe would take (V + E) for traversal, making the entire algorithm O((V + E) + (V log k)), which is still O(V log k).